# Generate Json Format in given order in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am new to python. I want to convert given string into json and I found `json.loads()` method to do that. But it generates json data in random order, i need them in orders because i am working with `keys()` and `values()` method of json.
Here is what I tried in the terminal:

```
    >> json.loads('{"a":"a","w":"w","b":"b","c":"c"}')
    >> {'b': 'b', 'w': 'w', 'c': 'c', 'a': 'a'}
```

Here the order in the json is jumbled. I want them in the same order I provided.

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered. You were doomed *before* you generated JSON.

Comment: closely related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-python-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary